# SP2010 Archive news articles on a publishing site

Tags: 2010, publishing-page, archive

I was wondring if there is an out of the box solution to archive news articles located in the pages library of an Enterprise Portal site.
E.g. would it be possible to use a workflow or the content organizer to move the articles to a pages library in a subsite called archive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use information rights management to handle expiration of the articles. This is typically done by setting up IRM to fire on some date based on the item creation date, like created + 1 year. When IRM is triggered, you can tell it to run a specific workflow. This could be deleting the item, or moving it to an archive folder/library depending on your requirement.

Comment: So maybe the status of a calculated field (Set to archive when current date equals publishing date + 1 year) can be the trigger for the archive workflow?

Comment: You don't necessarily need a calculated column for that, you can configure it as such from the Information Rights Management interface.